# ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1): STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a dataset consisting of both numeric and categorical data and I want to predict adverse outcomes for patients based on their medical characteristics. I defined a prediction pipeline for my dataset like so:

```py
X = dataset.drop(columns=['target'])
y = dataset['target']

# define categorical and numeric transformers
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('knnImputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

#  dispatch object columns to the categorical_transformer and remaining columns to numerical_transformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, selector(dtype_exclude="object")),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include="object"))
])

# Append classifier to preprocessing pipeline.
# Now we have a full prediction pipeline.
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

However, when running this code, I get the following warning message:

```
ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.
Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)

    model score: 0.988
```

Can someone explain to me what this warning means? I am new to machine learning so am a little lost as to what I can do to improve the prediction model. As you can see from the numeric_transformer, I scaled the data through standardisation. I am also confused as to how the model score is quite high and whether this is a good or bad thing.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The *warning* means what it mainly says: Suggestions to try to make the *solver* (the algorithm) converges.

---

`lbfgs` stand for: "Limited-memory Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno Algorithm". It is one of the solvers' algorithms provided by Scikit-Learn Library.

The term *limited-memory* simply means it stores **only a few** vectors that represent the gradients approximation implicitly.

It has better **convergence** on relatively *small* datasets.

---

But what is *algorithm convergence*?

In simple words. If the error of solving is ranging within very small range (i.e., it is almost not changing), then that means the algorithm reached the solution (*not necessary to be the best solution as it might be stuck at what so-called "local Optima"*).

On the other hand, if the error is ***varying noticeably*** (*even if the error is relatively small [like in your case the score was good], but rather the differences between the errors per iteration is greater than some tolerance*) then we say the algorithm did not converge.

Now, you need to know that Scikit-Learn API sometimes provides the user the option to specify the maximum number of iterations the algorithm should take while it's searching for the solution in an iterative manner:

```
LogisticRegression(... solver='lbfgs', max_iter=100 ...)
```

As you can see, the default solver in LogisticRegression is 'lbfgs' and the maximum number of iterations is 100 by default.

Final words, please, however, note that increasing the maximum number of iterations does not necessarily guarantee convergence, but it certainly helps!

---

### Update:

Based on your comment below, some tips to try (out of many) that might help the algorithm to converge are:

- Increase the *number of iterations*: As in this answer;
- Try a *different optimizer*: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640109/logistic-regression-python-solvers-defintions/52388406#52388406);
- Scale your data: Look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html);
- Add engineered features: Look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/discover-feature-engineering-how-to-engineer-features-and-how-to-get-good-at-it/);
- Data pre-processing: Look [here - use case](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80421/very-low-cross-val-score-for-regression-with-big-corr-between-feature-and-res/80422#80422) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning-3a5e293a5114);
- Add more data: Look [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-determine-sample-size-for-machine-learning-classification/answer/Yahya-Almardeny).

Comment: I increased the maximum number of iteration to 400 LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=400) and this has resolved the warning. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Going back to this question, any tips on other things I can try to help the algorithm converge?

Comment: I increased the max iterations to 1000 to get it to work.

Comment: For my data, which has a large randomness, max_iter=10000 was needed to make it converge.

Comment: Well explained, thank you!

Answer (score 55):

If you are getting the following error for any machine learning algorithm,

> ConvergenceWarning:
>
> lbfgs failed to converge (status=1): 
> STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in *[6.3. Preprocessing data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)*

Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options: *[LogisticRegression()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression)*

Then in that case you use an algorithm like

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
log_model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000)
```

because sometimes it will happen due to iteration.

Comment: This answer has been mentioned in the recent [Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/) and, as a result, quickly gained a few upvotes today.

Comment: Yes, and it's still a bad answer. "because sometimes it will happen due to iteration." is a fairly meaningless response...

Comment: Quote from the blog post: *"most copied downvoted answer"*

Comment: @jms still, as the post says, 'it appears to be a more concise version of the accepted answer (...) it is the perfect example of a “too long didn’t read” post.'

Comment: @GuilhermeGarnier sure the accepted answer is verbose, but the original poster seems to be fairly naive and probably required some extra background which the commenter was catering to.

Comment: This answer has been mentioned again in [StackOverflow Blog 2021-04-19](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know) and will surely attract more attention :)

Comment: The blog post seems to be surprised that this answer is coped more than the accepted answer - there's nothing to copy in the accepted answer!

Comment: I came here, because it was mentioned in [how often do people actually copy and paste (2021-12-30)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/30/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/?cb=1)

Comment: so came I, but now it **has** upvotes!

Answer (score 14):

to fix **Convergence warning** specify **max_iter** in the **LogisticRegression** to a higer value:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model=LogisticRegression(max_iter=3000)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression   
logReg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=3000)
```