# How to perform elastic-net for a classification problem?

Tags: python, classification, regularized

I am a noob and I have previously tackled a linear regression problem using regularised methods. That was all pretty straight forward but I now want to use elastic net on a classification problem.

I have run a baseline logistic regression model and the prediction scores are decent (accuracy and f1 score of ~80%). I know that some of my input features are highly correlated and I suspect that I am introducing multicollinearity, hence why I want to run an elastic net to see the impact on the coefficients and compare against the baseline.

I have done some googling and I understand I need to use SGDClassifier function for regularised logistics regression model. Is this the best way to perform this analysis and can anyone point me in the direction of a basic example with cross validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

Your question *really* should be broken up into multiple other questions, such as:

- How can I tell if my data is collinear?
- How to deal with collinear data in a machine learning problem?
- How can I convert logistic regression to elasticnet for classification?

I am going to focus on the third bullet above.

Additionally, there is no sample data, or even a [`minimum, complete, reproducible`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of code for us to go off of, so I am going to make some assumptions below.

## How can I use logistic regression for classification?

#### What's the difference between logistic regression and elasticnet?

First, let's understand *what is different about logistic regression vs elasticnet*. [This TowardsDataScience article](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-the-difference-between-linear-regression-lasso-ridge-and-elasticnet-8f997c60cf29) is fairly well written and goes into the details a little bit, and you should review it if you are unfamiliar. In short,

> Logistic Regression does not penalize the model for its weight choices, while elasticnet includes absolute value, and squared penalization tactics which are regularized with an `l1_ratio` coefficient.

#### What does that difference look like in code?

You can review the [source code for Logistic Regression here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L1012), but in short, lines `794-796` show the `alpha` and `beta` values changing when the penalty type is elasticnet:

#### What does this mean for an example?

Below is an example of implementing this in code using [`sklearn's Logistic Regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV). Some notes:

- I am using cross validation as requested, and have set it to 3 folds
- I would take this performance with a grain of salt -- there is a lot of feature engineering which should be done, and parameters such as the `l1_ratios` should absolutely be investigated. These values were totally arbitrary.

Produces outputs that look like:

```
Logistic Regression: 0.972027972027972 || Elasticnet: 0.9090909090909091

Logistic Regression
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.96      0.96      0.96        53
           1       0.98      0.98      0.98        90

    accuracy                           0.97       143
   macro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97       143
weighted avg       0.97      0.97      0.97       143

Elastic Net
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.93      0.81      0.87        53
           1       0.90      0.97      0.93        90

    accuracy                           0.91       143
   macro avg       0.92      0.89      0.90       143
weighted avg       0.91      0.91      0.91       143
```

Code below:

```
# Load libraries

# Load a toy dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

# Load the LogisticRegression classifier
# Note, use CV for cross-validation as requested in the question
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV

# Load some other sklearn functions
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Import other libraries
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Load the breast cancer dataset
X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

# Create your training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=2)

# Basic LogisticRegression algorithm
logistic_regression_classifier = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=3)
# SAGA should be considered more advanced and used over SAG. For more information, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640109/logistic-regression-python-solvers-defintions
# Note, you should probably tune this, these values are arbitrary
elastic_net_classifier = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=3, penalty='elasticnet', l1_ratios=[0.1, 0.5, 0.9], solver='saga')

# Train the models
logistic_regression_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
elastic_net_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Test the models
print("Logistic Regression: {} || Elasticnet: {}".format(logistic_regression_classifier.score(X_test, y_test), elastic_net_classifier.score(X_test, y_test)))

# Print out some more metrics
print("Logistic Regression")
print(classification_report(y_test, logistic_regression_classifier.predict(X_test)))
print("Elastic Net")
print(classification_report(y_test, elastic_net_classifier.predict(X_test)))
```

There is alternatively another method you can use, similarly to how the [`RidgeClassifierCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifier.html) functions, but we would need to write a bit of a wrapper around that as `sklearn` has not provided that.