# What is the difference between "newton-cg" and "newton-cholesky" solvers in sklearn LogisticRegression?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, newtons-method

I am confused about "newton-cg" and "newton-cholesky" explanations in different sources.
According to the [sklearn documentaion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#solvers)

> The “newton-cholesky” solver is an exact Newton solver that calculates the Hessian matrix and solves the resulting linear system.

While after reading wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640109/logistic-regression-python-solvers-definitions) about LogisticRegression solvers I thought that this is what exactly "newton-cg" does.

[Source](https://tminka.github.io/papers/logreg/minka-logreg.pdf) about comparison of different methods provided by sklearn documentation also did not really clarify things.

So what is the difference between them?

EDIT 1

I know that GPT answers are banned for now, but I think I found the answer.
According to GPT4:

> The "newton-cg" solver uses a Newton-CG conjugate gradient algorithm
> to minimize the objective function. This algorithm uses the gradient
> and the Hessian matrix (second-order derivative of the objective
> function) to iteratively find the minimum of the function. The Hessian
> matrix is approximated using the outer product of the gradient vector.
> This solver works well for small and medium-sized datasets.
>
> On the other hand, the "newton-cholesky" solver uses a Newton-CG
> algorithm with a Cholesky decomposition of the Hessian matrix. This
> solver is more efficient than "newton-cg" for large datasets, as it
> requires less memory and computational resources. However, it may not
> converge for some datasets.
>
> In summary, the "newton-cg" solver may be more accurate, but slower
> and less memory efficient for large datasets, while the
> "newton-cholesky" solver is faster and more memory efficient, but may
> not converge for some datasets. The choice between these solvers
> depends on the size and complexity of the dataset and the trade-off
> between accuracy and computational efficiency.

To me, it makes sense because it finely aligns with all provided sources. The ambiguity in sklearn documentation was mainly in the "calculate" part - they do not explicitly tell, how Hessian is calculated in the 'newton-cholesky' method and how it is done in the 'newton-cg' method at all.